# Ajax back forward problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i use Ajax in my page, and dynamicaly load content, but in this case my back/forward does't work. could you tell me how can i solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If user has changed the parameters I'm using to query Ajax then I use Session to store them